# How do I get the network usage of a server per-IP?

Tags: linux, network-monitoring, tcpdump, networking

I'd like to know a tool to programmatically measure, in KB/s, the load that each IP applies to a server.

So far, tcpdump does a good job at telling me the amount of packets sent per second, but I believe many are not shown (Downloading at 350KB/s while only outputting 150 packets per second).

Am I doing this the right way? iftop would be PERFECT for this but I need a program that can be interfaced via stdout (without ncurses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use tshark (it's a part of wireshark).

use

```
tshark -q -z conv,tcp
```

or

```
tshark -q -z conv,udp
```

or

```
tshark -q -z conv,ip
```

after send ctrl+c you will get something like this

[image]